# What is the right package to use hist2d on octave/cygwin?

Tags: plot, cygwin, octave

In octave I am used to the command `hist2d`. On Debian/Ubuntu this command is found in the package `octave-plot` (which contains also dxfwrite,
ginput, gtext, tics, tricontour, waitforbuttonpress, zoom) (`apt-get install octave-plot`). Now I have to use windows/cygwin, but I don't find such package.

Do you know how to install it?

Al.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The octave plot package has been unmaintained for many years. You will notice Debian no longer has it either. You can still [download](http://octave.sourceforge.net/plot/index.html) the package and install it manually though.

However, there's alternatives for those functions (most of them are in Octave core). For the specific case of `hist2d`, use [`hist3()`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/statistics/function/hist3.html) from the statistics package.